# Open source implementation of .NET Remoting

Tags: java, .net, remoting

Does anyone know of an open source implementation of .NET Remoting? Preferably in Java or another non-CLR language.

My current project needs to interface with a proprietary app with a good remoting interface from Java, but the only implementations that I have been able to find are [J-Integra](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/net.asp) and [JNBridgePro](http://www.jnbridge.com/jnbpro.htm).

I am aware that I could use Mono to glean the implementation specifics, but barring a ready-to-use library, I'd prefer an implementation that shows some of the type-marshalling issues that I'll need to deal with.

Comment: why design around remoting? if you design around arbitrary SOA, then you'll have more options *and* a more formal interface API (remoting tends to lead to accidentally chatty interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use a [SoapFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap.soapformatter.aspx) over HTTP.

Then you'll be able to use any platform (*capable of send strings over HTTP*) to invoke methods of your object.

Regards,
Giacomo